# Gtkmm, call of overloaded 'Scale()" is ambiguous

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3, gtkmm

According to [Gtkmm docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Scale.html) `Gtk::Scale::Scale` is overloaded constructor and can take nothing or `Gtk::Orientation`.

I created object:

```
Gtk::Scale m_scale;
```

And added it to `Gtk::HBox`

```
hbox.pack_start(m_scale, false, 0);
```

But it produces error:

```
 error: call of overloaded ‘Scale()’ is ambiguous
```

And it tells me that candidates are Gtk::Scale without any parameter and one with Gtk::Orientation.

How should I force to use Gtk::Scale constructor without parameters?

Thanks,
S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the constructor taking `Gtk::Orientation` has a default value for that parameter, therefore it can also be called with no arguments:

```
public:
  Scale();
  explicit Scale(Orientation orientation = ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
```

The keyword `explicit` here does not help, it only possibly disallows converting anything passed in to the `Orientation` type for it to match.

I say just provide the orientation value, it will at least be explicitly apparent which kind of Scale widget you are creating for anyone else reading the code.